# How to mean each cell in a 60x60 table (Matlab)

Tags: matrix, coordinates

I'm a beginner in Matlab so I'm sorry if my question seems simple for you (or not). I'll try to be as understandable as possible.

So first I have a .mat folder with 2 columns corresponding to X and Y coordinates, reflecting a cellular counting in a brain structure (1 folder = 1 subject, 8 subjects in total). I transform my XY coordinates of each subject in a "Matrix" of 60x60 dimensions. Example from 2 subjects :

> load S1 % .mat XY coordinates 1st subject
>
> load S2 % XY coordinates 2nd subject
>
> nbins=[60,60]
>
> Mx=hist3(S1,'Nbins',nbins)
>
> Mx2=hist3(S2,'Nbins',nbins)

So I have 2 "double" of 60x60.

What I want to do is really simple but I can't find a proper way to do it :
**I just want to mean my 2 matrices in a new 60x60 mean matrix**. So, meaning each cell, and not each column!

Maybe it's impossible to do this on a "double" table so I converted it in "Table":

> Tx=array2table(Mx)
>
> Tx2=array2table(Mx2)

But now... I don't have any idea on how to mean my matrices. My columns and rows don't have names, maybe it's a problem ?

This mean matrix will be plotted in a heat map and I will assess statistical tests on it.
(Same procedure with statistical tests : each cells will be tested between my mean matrices).

Can you help me with this ? Or just few tips ! Do no hesitate to ask if you have questions or if you want more details.

Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you could just average the values in both matrices:

```
load S1 % .mat XY coordinates 1st subject
load S2 % XY coordinates 2nd subject

nbins=[60,60]
Mx=hist3(S1,'Nbins',nbins)
Mx2=hist3(S2,'Nbins',nbins)
M_avg = (Mx+Mx2)/2; % average value
surf(X,Y,M_avg) ! can even plotted if X and Y have proper dimensions
```

Comment: It's perfect. It was so simple, i'm on it since 3 days! thank you!

Comment: if this solved your problems, you should consider accept the answer :)